# Como alterar o tamanho do texto e o padding das abas no tabHost?

Tags: android

Tenho um tabHost e precisava mudar o padding e o tamanho dos textos nas abas. Alguém sabe como fazer isso? via código ou via xml? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fala Daniel,

Você precisa criar um tema pra sua Activity que tem o tabHost la no AndroidManifest.xml, exemplo:

```
<activity 
     android:name="MyTabActivity" 
     android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Feito isso, você precisa adicionar esse tema la no seu style.xml (res/values/styles.xml), exemplo:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTabWidgetText" 
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Agora você consegue alterar, cor do texto, tamanho, estilo e etc...etc...etc...

Qualquer dúvida na implementação posta ai que te ajudo.

Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente! Abraços.